# Change boot order

Tags: boot, bios

I brought a laptop second hand(lenovo t440) and it works great. Now my problem is that it has a password on the bios and the seller didn't tell me anything about this password and now he isn't even responding to my texts. Anyway, i want to change the boot order so that i can install linux on this laptop but i can't because the bios is locked, i need help in finding an alternate solution to bios? i know it sounds stupid but maybe there is or some way that i can reset the password of my bios. Something else that i can think of is editing the boot order via windows, maybe the bios saves some files with the boot order inside the os and i can edit them so that it will suit my need. Any help is welcomed

Comment: Have you tried the default password "admin"?

Comment: 15-20 years ago I would advise changing the value of CMOS registers directly (via DEBUG.exe, for example)... Change the control sum - BIOS thinks the CMOS data is wrong - CMOS data clearing.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to reset the jumper.

Comment: See this, not easy....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vNJGD8fzt8

Comment: Also this, easier....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW-RLkzjAS8

Comment: the thing is i don't want to open my laptop case cause i'm not a computer expert, i'm afraid i will mes something up and boom, i'm wondering if i can get someone that repairs laptops to do what is in the easier video, i tried the password admin and a couple of other passwords and still nothing

Comment: You don't change the boot order in BIOS setup. Just press F12 (or F11, enter... depending on your BIOS) to open the boot selection menu

Comment: i tried that but the bios there are multiple drives excluded from boot selection and i cannot change that

Answer (score 0):

There is some chance that the password is stored in volatile memory, so you can try removing the CMOS battery from the motherboard, but most newer motherboards store this in flash memory so this is unlikely to work. Beyond that, you will have to contact the manufacturer. Sometimes there is a jumper on the mother board that you can remove to reset the BIOS password.

Comment: its not stored in volatile memory on that model.